# How to fix error trying to find user files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this script to copy this file to any user's Documents folder:

```
import getpass
import os

user = getpass.getuser()                                     #gets username
file = "try.py"                                              #file to copy

new_file = "C:\\Users\\", user,"\\Documents\\try.py" #folder in which the file shoud copy
os.rename(file, new_file)                                    #copy the file
```

The problem is, when I try to run it, IDLE show this error:

[image: error message]

I don't really understand what it means. Please note that I am a beginner in Python.

Comment: Maybe `file` and `new_file` are equal?

Comment: no, tried to use another name, same error occurs

Comment: please copy your error text into the question

Answer (score 3):

new_file is not a concatenated string but a tuple.

Try using this for concatenation of strings

```
new_file = "C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\Documents\\try.py"
```

Comment: was just about to say I fixed it... then read your message lol, thank you very much this is actually how to fix it, it now works.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!